# Request to add tag synonym from [webshop] to [ecommerce]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have enough rep yet to suggest a tag synonym, but this seems like a pretty straightforward case.

I propose we synonymize [webshop](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webshop) to [ecommerce](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce), as any ecommerce question that is not about a web shop would be either be off-topic or fall under a different tag like [affiliate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affiliate).

What do you think?

Comment: Only one question and it has no real value. I see no problem with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in agreement with you and John here. I believe "webshop" is primarily used internationally, outside the U.S. Since this site is accessed throughout the world, we occasionally see regional or less commonly used terminology here. For example, thanks to this site I now know that web hosting services are also known as "web hotels" in some parts of the world...

This is a perfect case use of what [tag synonyms](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) are for: tags that essentially mean the same thing, with one being more commonly used than the other(s). Users from different regions will still be able to find a suitable substitution by typing in the term they're familiar with.

I therefore made `webshop` a synonym of the *target* `ecommerce` tag, and merged the questions so that the `ecommerce` tag will appear in replace of the `webshop` tag. When someone starts to type in "webshop" as a tag, `ecommerce` will pop-up, indicating that's the more commonly used tag on this site.